# Multiple conditions with same statement JAVA

Tags: java

I was wondering if I could get some help with making my java look better. Currently I am working on some homework and it looks very messy when I right an if statement with multiple conditions like the one below. I am trying to see if str.charAt(p) is equal to any vowels however this looks horrible writing it out one by one. Is there a better way?

```
if(str.charAt(p) == 'a' || str.charAt(p) == 'b' || .......) {
    f += str.charAt(p);
}
```

Comment: You can auto format your code if you are using an IDE. You can also manually add a new parahraph after the || statement.

Comment: you can do it using regex. create a matcher object using '[a-z]' regex expression and check if the str.charAt(i) matches it.

Comment: Or put the vowels in an array and see if the character is contained in it. Or use a `switch` with fall-thrus, and/or extract `isVowel` into its own method so it doesn't clutter the mainline code, or...

Comment: @epcpu Since it is homework I assume regex would not be covered.  Though it would clearly be a better choice.

Comment: `b` isn't a vowel, is it?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I've heard it both ways. AEIOU and sometimes B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , you'r right, it doesn't looks good, but it's effective which is the most important part. You can do it with switch like this =>

```
switch (str.charAt(p)) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                f += str.charAt(p);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(ch + " is not a vowel.");
        }
```